# PL/Sql IF loop with multiple OR - IN's

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a pl/sql loop which looks like below:

```
IF A IN (1,2,3,4,5) OR B IN (1,2,3,4,5) OR C IN (1,2,3,4,5) 
THEN
   --Do Something--
ELSIF A IN (6,7) AND B IN (6,7) AND C IN (6,7) 
THEN
   --Do Something Else--
ELSE
   --Do Nothing--
END IF;
```

Is there a better way to write the above loop?

The above example is just for a reference. My original program consits of more conditions in the IF loop.

Kindly help me in optimizing it. I am out of ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "is there a better way"?  What don't you like about this code?

Comment: We have no context regarding what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have 8 variables to compare with 14 values. I just want to know if there is a better way to write it, as my current loop looks very big and shabby.

Comment: There is no `IF-LOOP`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm) (nested table) type to hold the values and the test conditions then you can use [`MULTISET'](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators006.htm) operations to compare them:

- `(a MULTISET INTERSECT DISTINCT b) IS NOT EMPTY` is the equivalent of the `OR` statements; and
- `(a MULTISET EXCEPT DISTINCT b) IS EMPTY` is the equivalent of the `AND` statements

I've wrapped the code in a function for ease of testing:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2dae3/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Number_Table_Type AS TABLE OF NUMBER
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Test_Multiple_Values (
  A IN NUMBER,
  B IN NUMBER,
  C IN NUMBER,
  D IN NUMBER,
  E IN NUMBER,
  F IN NUMBER,
  G IN NUMBER,
  H IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
AS
  inputs Number_Table_Type := Number_Table_Type( A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H );
BEGIN
  IF ( inputs MULTISET INTERSECT DISTINCT Number_Table_Type( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) ) IS NOT EMPTY THEN
     RETURN 1;
  ELSIF ( inputs MULTISET EXCEPT DISTINCT Number_Table_Type( 6, 7 ) ) IS EMPTY THEN
     RETURN 2;
  ELSE
     RETURN 3;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH inputs AS (
  SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B, 3 AS C, 4 AS D, 5 AS E, 6 AS F, 7 AS G, 8 AS H FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, Test_Multiple_Values( A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H ) FROM inputs
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2dae3/2/0)**:

```
| A | B |  C |  D |  E |  F |  G |  H | TEST_MULTIPLE_VALUES(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) |
|---|---|----|----|----|----|----|----|---------------------------------------|
| 1 | 2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |                                     1 |
| 6 | 7 |  6 |  7 |  6 |  7 |  6 |  7 |                                     2 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |                                     3 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `CASE` statement. It will be more readable than `IF` statement.
[Check here for more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/04_struc.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE
WHEN (A IN (1,2,3,4,5) OR B IN (1,2,3,4,5) OR C IN (1,2,3,4,5)) THEN 
--do something
WHEN (A IN (6,7) AND B IN (6,7) AND C IN (6,7)) THEN 
--do something
ELSE 
--do nothing
END CASE;
```